# how can i reduce the size of the docker image

Tags: docker, anaconda, raspberry-pi4

i'm new with docker,and i created a docker image with Dockerfile as follows, it's used for a raspberry pi so all the packages are needed, i read the articles of multistage of dockerfile, but i don't understand much, how can i reduce the size of the image to simplify this deployment on raspberry？

```
FROM continuumio/anaconda3:latest
RUN conda create -y -n dcase2020 python=3.7
SHELL ["conda", "run", "-n", "dcase2020", "/bin/bash", "-c"]
RUN conda install -c conda-forge vim -y
RUN conda install pyaudio
RUN pip install librosa
RUN conda install psutil
RUN pip install psds_eval
RUN conda install -y pandas h5py scipy \
        &&conda install -y pytorch torchvision -c pytorch \
        &&conda install -y pysoundfile youtube-dl tqdm -c conda-forge \
        &&conda install -y ffmpeg -c conda-forge \
        &&pip install dcase_util \
        &&pip install sed-eval

EXPOSE 80
CMD [“bash”]
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: See https://uwekorn.com/2021/03/01/deploying-conda-environments-in-docker-how-to-do-it-right.html

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a new environment that probably only contains the requirements for your project, so no use in having the huge anaconda base env as extra weight, instead, just switch to a `miniconda` container like `continuumio/miniconda3`

Comment: good idea ! thank you very much! btw, do you know can we apply multistage of docker in this situation?